# Typescript default value for index type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-constraints

Consider this snippet from the [Index types section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) in the Typescript docs:

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
    return o[propertyName]; // o[propertyName] is of type T[K]
}
```

This function returns one of the properties of `o` and the rather elaborate type signature makes sure the type checker evaluates whether this property actually exists at compile time, which is pretty neat.

For a different but similar function, I would like to have `propertyName` a default value, so it does not have to be passed explicitly, i.e.

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K = "default"): T[K]
```

The compiler does not like this, though, and throws the following error at the function definition:

```
Type '"default"' is not assignable to type 'K'.
'"default"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
```

I get that numbers and symbols(?) can also be valid indices, but not why that precludes me from assigning a string as default value for `propertyName`. Could someone explain why this is a problem and if it's possible to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two possible problems here:

1. `T` might not have `"default"` property
2. `getProperty` can be called with providing generic type parameters explicitly
   e.g. `getProperty<Foo, "someProp">(...)`, so `"default"` can't be assigned to this type

---

One possible solution would be defining [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads): one without property name (using default) and another allowing to provide property name:

```
function getProperty<T extends { "default"?: any }>(o: T): T["default"]
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K]
function getProperty(o: any, propertyName = "default") {
    return o[propertyName];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AdVZQCeAPACqKoAeUqYAJgM6IDeiARPasAIYgA2UdgH4AXIh5giiAL4A+ABRxxZAJQqA2p259B7ALoAoUJFgIU6bHgLFyAGkQBpSjTpNEAa1RE4wRGUVlfwdcHHxCIgA5HgBbVHFHdX8NRyMTaHgkNEwwmyIlcUkiENyI6LjEAF4OLl4BIVVWQ0QWxCx0ECwkOA1Q6zLY1H0AbkMZIA)

Comment: I think the possibility of calling with explicit generic paramaters was the problem. I did not know that was possible. I don't think option problem 1. applies here, since the error was raised at function definition rather than at a call. I didn't mention this explicitly so I'll make an edit. Furthermore your approach with overloads was exactly what I needed. Thanks!